# XPath: Help in locating a specific element in a DOM scraped using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, html, dom, xpath, htmlunit

I am scraping a webpage using HTMLUnit and have collected a List of DOM nodes from the webpage.

Inside each of these "company" DOM nodes is some data I want to scrape. For example I want the telephone number text from inside this node:

Now, this element would be a child of a div element which is in turn a child of another div element inside the company node. What would be the correct XPath line to access it? Here is my latest attempt which returned nothing.

```
 List<DomNode> companies = (List<DomNode>) page.getByXPath("//li[@class='featured block twoblock    boxshadow']");
        for (int j = 0; j < companies.size(); j++) {

            DomNode company = companies.get(j);

                // retrieve telephone number
                DomNode telephone = (DomNode) company.getByXPath(
                        "//li[@data-pvd-p='"+j+1+"']/div[@class='listingWrapper']/div[@class='itemInfo']/span[@class='tel']").get(0);
```

}

Here is a sample of the HTML, what:

```
        <li class="featured block twoblock boxshadow" data-pvd-p="3" data-pvd-c="0046176330000011028" data-pvd-et="sv" data-pvd-l="true">

    <div class="listingWrapper" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="">
        <a href="/Craddock-Electrical-Services-Ltd/0046176330000011028/"></a>
        <div class="itemInfo">
            <div class="tradeImage" itemprop="member" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></div>
            <h2>
                <a itemprop="name" href="/Craddock-Electrical-Services-Ltd/0046176330000011028/"></a>
            </h2>
            <span class="tel" itemprop="telephone"></span>
            <div class="listLinks"></div>
            <div id="addressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemInfo2"></div>
        <div class="clearLeft"></div>
        <ul class="features"></ul>
        <div class="clearLeft"></div>
        <p class="promo" itemprop="description"></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the current state of my XPath code.

```
List<DomNode> companies = (List<DomNode>) page
                .getByXPath("//li[contains(@class, 'featured block')]");
        for (int j = 0; j < companies.size(); j++) {

            String url = "";
            DomNode company = companies.get(j);
            DomElement web = null;

            // retrieve name
            DomNode name = (DomNode) company.getByXPath("//a[@itemprop='name']").get(j);

            if (companiesLogged.contains(name.getTextContent().trim()) != true) {
                companiesLogged.add(name.getTextContent().trim());

                // retrieve telephone number
                DomNode telephone = (DomNode) company.getByXPath("div[@class='listingWrapper']/div[@class='itemInfo']/span[@class='tel']").get(0);


                // retrieve website
                try{
                web = (DomElement) company.getByXPath("div[@class='listingWrapper']/div[@class='itemInfo']" +
                        "/div[@class='listLinks']/a[@id='linkWebsite']").get(0);
                } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    System.out.print(" (No Website) ");
                }

                try{
                url = web.getAttribute("href");
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    url = "N/A";
                }

                System.out.println(name.getTextContent().trim() + "   "
                        + telephone.getTextContent().trim()
                 +"   "+url.trim());

            } else {
                System.out.println("Company already logged");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the XML/XHTML you're targeting, or a snippet from it so we can make a better suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I see is how you're retrieving the group of `<li>` nodes. Just looking at your `@class` attribute, you can't really tell how many spaces are in "`featured block twoblock    boxshadow`", but that XPath will only return a result if it is *exactly equal to it*. 
In that regard, try using something more flexible like `contains()`, i.e. `//li[contains(@class, 'featured block')]`.

Without seeing what source you're targeting I can't suggest much more, but will update the answer when it's added to the question.

I've tried your XPath (just the /div part, since that's what was provided) on the given snippet and got back `<span class="tel" itemprop="telephone"/>` as a result. Looks like an issue with how you're retrieving the `<li>`  company nodes.

**Update 2:**
From your updated XML snippet, your first XPath `//li[@class='featured block twoblock    boxshadow']"` doesn't look like it will match the parent `<li>` node, based on what I mentioned with the spaces before. Secondly if it did, you are checking the `<li>` node's attributes twice on separate queries, and assuming that the index you're giving the `data-pvd-p` value (starts at 3 in the snippet) will always match the list index (starts at 0, with your +1 added). I'd suggest removing this portion `//li[@data-pvd-p='"+j+1+"']` and beginning with the `//div`.

So something like this:

```
List<DomNode> companies = (List<DomNode>) page.getByXPath("//li[contains(@class, 'featured block']");
        for (DomNode node : companies) {

                // retrieve telephone number
                DomNode telephone = (DomNode) node.getByXPath(
                        "div[@class='listingWrapper']/div[@class='itemInfo']/span[@class='tel']").get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to show the HTML. I'll also use your suggestion for the <li> nodes.

Comment: @GreenGodot Your XPath from the /div onward seems to be fine, if you want to post the full snippet with the encasing <li> I can try it out as well.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I thought I included it the first time.

Comment: Np, it helps to post as much info as possible related to the issue starting out. Updated the answer

Comment: Apologies but just as an aside. Not all snippets like the one in my original question may necessarily have a telephone number. So when I am storing the number it may be associated with the wrong company. Is there any way to check if that element exists as a child element of the original <li> tag before I do anything else?

Comment: @GreenGodot Not sure I follow. How are you storing the number? You'll only get a telephone number for a company if the *there is* a child element under the `<li>` tag

Comment: The number is being stored as a string value. The snippet I am showing is a simplified version of my code in which I also aim to obtain the name of a company, its e-mail etc. In the XPATH, the characters "//" are used which I believe searches the entire HTML document. If I retrieve them as I do in the snippet, I will just get the first telephone number  each time and not the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc. If I use my for loop to retrieve them (node.getByXPath(....).get(j)) this will eventually cause a mismatch as a business that does not have a number will get that number instead. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, yes I get what you're saying. `//` does start from the root of the node and search all of the contents, so you could remove it completely from the second XPath(relative vs absolute XPath) and you will only get the results within that `<li>` node, so they will never be mismatched. But from the snippet, it looks like there is only 1 company per `<div class="listingWrapper"` node, so this would work. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: This is quite frustrating. There is indeed only one company per listWrapper. Yet I am somehow getting mismatches still. When you say // starts at the root of the node does that mean it considers only the entire listwrapper node it is currently in and not the whole HTML page? As it is definitely still doing the entire page when searching. Removing // from the XPath really seems to throw it off. For clarification, I'll update my code yet again, sorry about this.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, what I was looking for was ".//" which would search for elements relative to my company node. Since your answer was still helpful regardless I shall mark it as correct!